# How to check value contains character AND a number > x

Tags: mysql

I've got values stored in a table that are looking like this:

```
lk_release
A1
A2
C1
C2
C3
D1
D2
D3
```

I want to check if a value contains a certain character, like "C", AND if the number next to it is greater than 2.

My current `Select-Statement` looks like this:

```
SELECT distinct LK_Release FROM customer_requirement
WHERE LK_Release LIKE "%C%"
AND ... ;
```

Now i want to check if the number next to the values with "C" are bigger than 2.
Is there simple way to do this? I was thinking of using some sub-queries, but i can't figure out a solution. Modifying the stored data is not an option.

Comment: So the pattern is always same ?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
  from customer_requirement 
  where lk_release like "%C%" 
    and right(lk_release, 1) > 2
```

here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ca77/1

Note it relies on it always being a single digit, and always being at the end of the string.

Comment: Wow, fast and correct answer. This is working as intended. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_requirement
WHERE lk_release like "%C%" and SUBSTR(LK_Release,2,1) >2
```